# Meteor: How can I create a many-to-many relationship between two collections linked by ids?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have two collections. One is called **Posts** and the other is called **Categories**. In the **Posts** collection, are individual posts which have an id. Shown in the picture as `id: 1291,` for this particular post, which is an integer, not a string.

[image]

The second collection is the **Categories** collection which contains the categories each of the posts belong to, ***most importantly***, within each category in the **Categories** collection is an *array of the posts* that belong to that category. Pay attention to `posts.ID` which in this case is `ID: 1291,` This ID is the **post id** in the **Posts** collection

### Summery.

- There is a **Posts** collection which has *individual* posts. Those
  *individual* posts belong to different categories.
- There is also the **Categories** collection which has the individual categories.
  In each category is an *array* of the `posts` that belong to
  that category but with few *post objects* I can utilise.

[image]

### THE PROBLEM

*I have a flow that goes like this.*

The user scrolls through a list of categories and clicks on a category from the Categories collection with the goal of viewing the posts within that category.

```
<template name="category">
    {{#each categories}}
      <span class="title"><a href="/category/{{_id}}">{{name}}</a></span>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

As it stands, When the user performs this action, they view the posts that are already in category that belongs to the **Categories** collection  (*remember the posts array within the category collection*) like this

```
Template.singleCategory.helpers({
  categories() {
    var id = FlowRouter.getParam('_id');
    return Categories.find({
      _id: id
    }, {
      sort: {
        timestamp: 1
      },
      limit: 100
    });
  }
});
```

But these posts in the **Categories** collection do not have certain key objects found in the **Posts** collection, plus I want to get rid on the posts in the categories.

### Goal

Instead of using these posts found in the **Categories** collection, I would like to use the posts found in the **Posts** collection and I would like to create the relationship using the similar Ids they share. So when a user clicks on a category, the posts they should see should come from the **Posts** collection, linked by the `post ID` in the **Categories** collection which is identical to the `post id` in the **Posts** collection.

### Code

Here is the code. I'm trying to say the following:

> In this single category being viewed by the user after they clicked it from the list of other categories, **do not** show the posts embedded in the **Categories** collection, *Instead*, return the **Posts** collection. In this **Posts** collection, find each `post id`, then match it to `ID` from `category.posts` within the **Categories** collection, then Show the
>   objects from **Posts** collection, not `category.posts`.

```
  Template.singleCategory.helpers({
      posts(){
        return Posts.find({ ID: {$in: this.posts }});
      }
    });
```

However, I cannot seem to get it to work. I'm getting the error

```
Exception in template helper: Error: $in needs an array
```

the posts in the category collection are an array.

how can I solve this?

### Edited

Building on the code in the answer section I had to treat category.posts so its an array. I'm getting the results I want, well, to an extent, some posts are not coming through. I wonder, could this code be better?

```
Template.Category.helpers({
  categories(){
    var id = FlowRouter.getParam('_id');
//create a variable with the correct category by id
var category = Category.findOne(id, {
  sort: {
    timestamp: 1
  },
  limit: 100
});
console.log(category);
//target ID within posts
var postArray = category.posts;
console.log(postArray);
//treat the object, clean it up to prepare it for becoming an array
      var postArrayStr = JSON.stringify(postArray).replace(/ID/g, '').replace(/\[|\]/g, '').replace(/""/g, '').replace(/:/g, '').replace(/\{|\}/gi, '');
//create an array
      var idsArray = postArrayStr.split(',').map(function(item) {
        return parseInt(item, 10);
      });
//match it to posts id
      var matchi = Posts.find({
  id: {
    $in: idsArray
  }
}).fetch();
      //
      console.log(matchi);
      //return it
      return matchi;

  }

});
```

Comment: You should probably first debug your code and make sure `this.posts` is really what you think it is.

Comment: can a post belong to more than one category?

Comment: A post can belong to many categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is having in the category collection an array with just the post mongo's _id field (which is unique).

Then in the helper you can query the post collection to return all the posts with those ids.

So it would be something like this:

```
Template.singleCategory.helpers({
  posts(){
    var id = FlowRouter.getParam('_id');
    var category = Category.findOne(id, {sort: {timestamp: 1},limit: 100 })

    var postArray = category.posts
    // example --> ["rCBWsKLCAWghBRJg4", "yMDtnDSo43ZDEcqpu", "cQeJntQtvwiHpgdZ9"]

    return Posts.find( {_id: {$in: postArray}});
    // it will return an array oj objects where each object is a post from the posts collection : [Object, Object, Object]
  }
});
```

There are better way to do it but I think this solution may fix your problem without change too many things

Comment: Thank you @Giova.panasiti - you gave me a good way to approach it, a much more elegant way than how i was doing it. I was still having problems though but it was to do with the nature of the object 'category.posts'. I needed it to be an array so I can use the with '$in' so I build up on the code to a point where can get the posts. However, there are some posts which are not picked up even though they are there. I still can't figure that out. Anyway take a look at the edited section of the post